# Matplotlib ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is the error I am encountering with MatplotLib:

```
PS D:\Anto_Local_Files\py\Dam Safety>  d:; cd 'd:\Anto_Local_Files\py\Dam Safety'; & 'c:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.11.exe' 'c:\Users\acer\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '50630' '--' 'd:\Anto_Local_Files\py\Dam Safety\Dams with percent storage plot.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Anto_Local_Files\py\Dam Safety\Dams with percent storage plot.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 272, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 266, in _check_versions
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\kiwisolver\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._cext import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

reinstall matplotlip

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib
```

and also the error shows your python enviornment is not in correct path
Check that in "PATH" inside "Enviornment variable[image]"

Comment: I added the path and added two dll files msvcr71, msvcp71 still not error solved

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by downloading Microsoft [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145) from Microsoft.